# Vertically align of paragraph to the bottom of a div wont work

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem:

I have a div and in this div i have a paragraph ( p tag ) which contains like 5 images. I want that whole paragraph to be positioned at the bottom of the div container, but i dont manage to get it done, I have tried it with make the paragraph display inline box, or table cell, and vertically align it to bottom, but nothing works.

Maybe sombody can help me?

Code:

Div Container:

```
#info {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    width:770px;
    height:600px;
    background:#fcfcfc;
    border:thin solid;
    border-color:#CCC;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Paragraph which should be at bottom of div

```
 <p style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom;">
        <!-- Twitch Chat - Insert Twitch Id -->
        <a href="http://de.twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=guardsmanbob&amp;popout_chat=true"><img id="ov" src="../Images/List/diverse/button_twitchchat.png"  /></a> 
        <!-- IRC Chat - Insert Quakenet id -->
        <a href="http://webchat.quakenet.org/?channels=guardsmanbob"><img id="ov" src="../Images/List/diverse/button_ircchat.png"  /></a>
        <!-- Facebook - Insert Facebook URL --> 
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Guardsman-Bob/316802258368275"><img id="ov" src="../Images/List/diverse/button_facebook.png" /></a>
        <!-- Twitter - Insert Twitter URL --> 
        <a href="https://twitter.com/GuardsmanBob"><img id="ov" src="../Images/List/diverse/button_twitter.png"  /></a> 
        <!-- Leaguepedia - Insert Leaguepedia URL -->
        <a href="http://leaguepedia.com/wiki/GuardsmanBob"><img id="ov" src="../Images/List/diverse/button_leaguepedia.png"  /></a>
        </p>
```

Comment: do you know the height of the images and are they always going to be the same?

Comment: yes i know the height and yes they are always the same, why?

Comment: you can realize vertical alignment via "display: table-cell" for your "a-tags". P must have "display: table;"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know the height of your p tag and it will always be the same you can use something like this:

for the parent container of the paragraph add the following styles:

```
.parent {position:relative; padding-bottom:20px; /*height of your images plus any padding for your paragraph*/}
```

then you can position your images absolutely:

```
 p {position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;}
```

Comment: hey another question:
I have decided to also put the object, which is on top of the images, to the bottom, so i just set the padding to 450 and put the object also in the p Tag. Put than it wont work again and the div is just getting bigger the size of the padding I set. Any idea why?

Comment: what is the object and the height of it?

Comment: `<object style="position:absolute; bottom:30; left:0;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="410" width="750" id="live_embed_player_flash" data=@@(data)@@><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://de.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value=@@(host)@@ /></object>`

Comment: ok, as you have positioned this absolute, you need to take it out of the p tag and put it into the parent - I take it your images are 30px high? Also put px after the 30

Comment: so i the parent i set to padding bottom 450px, the object i set as in the code (its not in a p) and than the images are in a p which i set as you told me in your answer. Sadly the positioning is completly broken now, the div is 450px higher, the object is on top and the images at the bottom.

Comment: put the object in a div and put the styles onto the div instead of the object - I don't think you can style objects directly - or some browsers have troubles with that

Comment: Got it now!!
I just removed the padding on the parent, now it seems to work fine.
thx for your help again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
<div id="info" style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute; bottom: 50px;">
        <p>[your images]</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

"50px" above needs to equal the height of the images in the `<p>` tag.

**Or if the image height is variable**, you could use the technique found here: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html. You would have to modify the margins in a manner to result in the positioning you require, but the technique linked to would give you want you need.